# How to trigger an custom alert condition of multiples from the basic search of Splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am new to Splunk and facing an issue while setting up the custom alert.
The results as shown in Table 1.
[image: Basic search results in splunk]
I have tried the one which is highlighted in red color below is not working.
[image: custom multiple condition search]

How do I configure for both of the values ie., DCOEtransfercount and NDMCopycount?

Note: Ignore the DCOEtransfercount/NDMCopycount labels in both of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier and simpler to put the trigger criteria in the search and have the alert trigger when the number of results is not zero.

```
<<your current search>>
| where (DCOEtransfercount=1 AND NDNCopycount=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Splunk is case-senstive ... except where it isn't :)

By default `search` ANDs

But if you want to be *explicit*, you *must* all-caps `AND` - just like you *must* all-caps `OR`:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp "someval" "someotherval"
```

Is the *same* as:

```
index=ndx AND sourcetype=srctp AND "someval" AND "someotherval"
```

Splunk views "and" as raw text to look for, whereas "AND" is an operator

So this should be what you're looking for (though I generally agree with @[RichG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227420/richg)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76166231/4418) wherein he says you should make the filter in the Alert, and only send if the results are greater than 0):

```
search NDMCopycount=1 DCOEtransfercount=* NOT (DCOEtransfercount IN(0,1))
```